# xampp codeigniter mac

Tags: macos, codeigniter, xampp

I have codeigniter setup to work on my mac with 10.6 xampp 1.7.3. it seems to work but now cannot find the controller I have created. it gives me a 404 error page not found. I am not using any htaccess files and I have not special features setup. everything is setup like it should be from default settings. the name of my controller is loginpage and have made it the default route in the routes.php file. what should I be looking for?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have index.php in your URL?

Comment: http://localhost/codeigniter_folder/index.php/controller/function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper URL syntax is

`http://siteroot/index.php/controller/function/argument`